# How to abbreviate data processing code using lambda expression in java?

Tags: java, lambda, stream

I have a problem to write logically same code using lambda expressions in Blank space.
How to abbreviate //Question Code ~ Question Code // block in one sentence using lambda Expression??

```java
public class Student {
    public enum Sex{MALE,FEMALE}
    public enum City{Seoul,Busan}
    private String name;
    private int score;
    private Sex sex;
    private City city;
    Student(String name,int score,Sex sex,City city){
        this.name=name;
        this.score=score;
        this.sex=sex;
        this.city=city;
    }
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public int getScore() {return score;}
    public void setScore(int score) {this.score = score;}
    public Sex getSex() {return sex;}
    public void setSex(Sex sex) {this.sex = sex;}
    public City getCity() {return city;}
    public void setCity(City city) {this.city = city;}
}
```

```java
public class GroupingExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> totalList= new ArrayList<>();
        totalList.add(new Student("Nafla",100,Student.Sex.MALE,Student.City.Seoul));
        totalList.add(new Student("Loopy",99,Student.Sex.MALE,Student.City.Seoul));
        totalList.add(new Student("Paloalto",98,Student.Sex.MALE,Student.City.Busan));
        totalList.add(new Student("KidMilli",97,Student.Sex.MALE,Student.City.Busan));
        totalList.add(new Student("YunWhey",90,Student.Sex.FEMALE,Student.City.Seoul));
        totalList.add(new Student("JackyWai",100,Student.Sex.FEMALE,Student.City.Seoul));

//Question Code
Stream<Student> totalStream= totalList.stream();
Function<Student,Student.Sex> classifier = Student :: getSex; 
Collector<Student,?,Map<Student.Sex,List<Student>>> collector = Collectors.groupingBy(classifier);

Map<Student.Sex,List<Student>> mapBySex = totalStream.collect(collector);
//Question Code 

//Write the logically same code at underline using Lambda Expression. 

Map<Student.Sex,List<Student>> mapBySexWithLambda = "Blank space"
```

Comment: It's as simple as replacing each variable with the value assigned to it unless you're satisfied by the simplification. `Map<Student.Sex, List<Student>> mapBySexWithLambda = totalList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student -> student.getSex()))`

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it in one line:

```
Map<Student.Sex, List<Student>> mapBySexWithLambda = totalList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getSex));
```

This is called chaining.

Comment: @Mustahsan agreed.